# Should I use multiple databases in MySQL for my "hosting" platform?

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

My idea is to offer a platform where the clients can create a personal site with a custom CMS, and then they will be able to customize their site using plugins.

My question is: should I create a DB for each client?
I would choose this solution for two reasons:

- The plugins are developed by people outside the company, so they could cause problems to all users if only one DB is used, I think.
- The access could be more efficient because the data of each user are stored separately.

Comment: Unless the plugins are MySQL stored procedures, access to the plugins is independent of the MySQL databases.

Comment: If you will have own database for each client then you need manage all that databases, easiest way to have one database and encrypt data for each client